# Como adicionar mais um campo de formulário no wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Na parte de "adicionar novo" no wordpress tem apenas dois campos de formulário, eu preciso colocar mais, mas é possível fazer isto criando um plugin ?

Comment: Presumo que já esteja usando algum plugin para criar o form, se sim, qual plugin já esta usando?

Comment: Nenhum, só quero criar um plugin para aumentar o formulário do wordpress de cadastro de postagem.

Comment: Entendi, fala do formulário do "Meta" para postagens. Mas que tipos de campos adicionais você gostaria de adicionar?

Comment: um <textarea rows="5" cols="80">

Answer (score 1):

Existem 2 plugins relativamente populares para este uso:

### [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

O plugin Advanced Custom Fields suporta os campos seguintes formatos:

Text, Text Area, Number, Email, Password, WYSIWYG, Image, File, Select, Checkbox, Radio Buttons, True / False, Page Link, Post Object, Relationship, Taxonomy, User, Google Maps, Date Picker, Color Picker, Tab, Message e Customizado por você.

- [Download](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

### [PODS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/)

- [Download](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/)

---

> **Nota 1:** Esta resposta esta em edição, estou traduzindo os textos
>
> **Nota 2:** Existe mais plugins para isto, mas uns eram pagos e outros eu não consegui ter certeza do funcionamento, irei editar a resposta conforme puder testar estes outros plugins